# Drupal & Moodle integration for implemention single sign on functionality by REST SErver

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, moodle

I have to integrate drupal with moodle, for that firstly I need to setup single sign on process i.e. SSO in both the drupal and moodle site.
I followed the tutorial that is available on the github at:
https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Drupal-Side
https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Moodle-Side

The Drupal server side is working fine but this link does not return anything. It just output empty page  /drupalservice/system/connect

The CSRF token is generated at /services/session/token and it returns fine.
According to drupal side configuration this link /drupalservice/muser returns the list of all user and it works fine. 
But the moodle site I am getting error:
Success : cookies: SSO Cookie discovered properly
Fail : system/connect: User session data reachable but you aren't logged in!
Fail : user/login: Login service unreachable. Check that User/actions/login is enabled in the Drupal moodle services endpoint.
Fail : muser/Index: An authentication error occurred
What should I do now I searched lots of pages and check all the configuration many times.

When I use Advanced Rest Client on chrome browser I get the complete proper response but I am not getting on the site.